# How do I add or remove security groups from ENIs using Boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm using the [Boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) Python interface to manage my EC2 software-defined networking and I'm writing a method to manage Security Groups on Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs).

I don't know how to tell EC2 to add or remove security groups to/from an ENI.

My approach thus far is essentially:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_ec2()

my_eni = conn.get_all_network_interfaces(['eni-xxxx1234'])[0]
my_eni_groups = my_eni.groups
my_eni_sg_ids = [ x.id for x in my_eni_groups ]

desired_sg_state = ['sg-xxxx1234','sg-xxxx5678']

# if present, do nothing, else, add it somehow..
for sg in desired_sg_state:
    if sg in my_eni_sg_ids:
        print('Okay: ', sg)
    else:
        # not sure what method to use here!
```

I searched through the documentation and couldn't find anything about association/disassociation of Security Groups in the `boto.ec2.securitygroup` or `boto.ec2.networkinterface` objects.  I'm certain that there's a way to do that, but it's not obvious to me.

Comment: A matter of style, but in Python we typically indent 4 spaces. :P ok, you fixed it, plus one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant action is at the [`boto.ec2.connection`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.connection) level -- you can use [`modify_network_interface_attribute`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.modify_network_interface_attribute) to make changes to security groups on Elastic Network Interfaces:

```
import boto

sg_string_list = ['sg-xxxx1234', 'sg-xxxx5678']

conn = boto.connect_ec2()
conn.modify_network_interface_attribute(interface_id=eni_id,
                                        attr='groupSet',
                                        value=sg_string_list)
```

Where the generalized form is:
`modify_network_interface_attribute(interface_id, attr, value, attachment_id=None, dry_run=False)`.

It's important to remember that you're specifying the state that you want the ENI *to be in* and not simply adding/removing SGs with the `modify_network_interface_attribute` call; if you want additive behavior, first get the current SG list and then append your new SG:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_ec2()

my_eni_groups = conn.get_all_network_interfaces(['eni-1582af5d'])[0].groups
my_eni_sg_ids = [ x.id for x in my_eni_groups ]

add_sg = 'sg-xxxx1234'

if add_sg not in my_eni_sg_ids:
    my_eni_sg_ids.append(add_sg)

    #only need to call this if we modified the list
    conn.modify_network_interface_attribute(interface_id=eni_id,
                                            attr='groupSet',
                                            value=my_eni_sg_ids)
```

There's not a one-to-one mapping of request parameters between the [EC2 documentation of the endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute.html) and [Boto's parameters](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.modify_network_interface_attribute), so be sure to see the attribute option names in the Boto documentation or by [visiting the source code](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/cb8aeec987ddcd5fecd206e38777b9a15cb0bcab/boto/ec2/connection.py#L1138-L1139) (please note that you may need to change branches to match your version (and potentially the linked line number)).